# 'items(ID)' vs 'getitembyid(ID)' in SharePoint REST API

Tags: 2013, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, list-item

I am trying to get the last modified details and it seems to me SharePoint REST APIs behaves different for query `items(ID)` vs `getitembyid(ID)`.

The below query with `items(ID)` works.

```
http://server/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<LIST NAME>')/items(31)
?$select=Editor/Title,OData__UIVersionString,Modified&$expand=Editor
```

But the below query with `getitembyid(ID)` throws error.

```
http://server/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<LIST NAME>')/getitembyid(31)
?$select=Editor/Title,OData__UIVersionString,Modified&$expand=Editor
```

The error that is shown is:

```
<m:error
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <m:code>-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException</m:code>
    <m:message xml:lang="en-US">The $expand query is not valid for field 'Editor'.</m:message>
    <m:innererror>
        <m:message>The $expand query is not valid for field 'Editor'.</m:message>
        <m:type>Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException</m:type>
        <m:stacktrace>
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.CheckExpandedLookupField(RESTfulQuery query)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.TryWriteAsOData(ServerStub serverStub, Uri path, ODataWriter writer, RESTfulQuery query, ProxyContext proxyContext)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.Write(Object value, Uri path, ODataWriter writer, RESTfulQuery query, ProxyContext proxyContext)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.Process()
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.ProcessRequest()
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestService.ProcessQuery(Stream inputStream, IList`1 pendingDisposableContainer)
</m:stacktrace>
        <m:internalexception>
            <m:message>The $expand query is not valid for field 'Editor'.</m:message>
            <m:type>
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException
</m:type>
            <m:stacktrace/>
        </m:internalexception>
    </m:innererror>
</m:error>
```

Why does `getitembyid(ID)` does not work? What are the difference between `items(ID)` vs `getitembyid(ID)`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use getById(Id) instead of getitembyid(Id)

as far as I know both are same,you can use both items(Id) or getById(Id).

we use Items(ID) in rest api and getById in JSOM code.

Comment: I think there is no command as `getById`. I get error `Cannot find resource for the request getById.` when I try to use it.

Comment: @ naveem. The proper endpoint url is "_api/web/lists/getbytitle(listname')/items/getbyid(id)". But both items(Id) or getById(Id) getting item from "ListItemCollection". so both may be same.

Comment: `items/getbyid` worked! But whats the difference between `items(ID)` vs `getitembyid(ID)`?